# IntelliJ Idea: remote debug option is missing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I need to debug remote java code with IntelliJ Idea 10.5 (Ultimate Edition)

When I create new debug configuration, host and port just don't appear there.

How can I turn on remote debugging?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you create the configuration of **Remote** type:

[image: remote]

Try disabling third-party plug-ins if it doesn't help, they may break standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the remote option was missing completely from the list of default configuration types, so I could not add a remote configuration.

The fix was simple: restart IDEA.